# How to perform MongoDB CRUD operations through javascript?

Tags: replication, mongodb, sharding

I'm trying to automate modifications made on tag ranges. But I keep getting an "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at ..." error at the first 'db.tags.remove...'.

```
...
today = yyyy+mm+dd;
balancing = sh.getBalancerState();

if (! balancing) {
    conn = new Mongo("mongoserver.mydomain.com:27017");
    db = conn.getDB("config");
    db.tags.remove({ _id: { ns: "mydb.mycoll", "min": { "day:" MinKey }}, tag: "LTS" });
    db.tags.remove({ _id: { ns: "mydb.mycoll", "max": { "day:" MaxKey }}, tag: "STS" });
    sh.addTagRange("mydb.mycoll", { day: MinKey }, { day: today }, "LTS");
    sh.addTagRange("mydb.mycoll", { day: today }, { day: MaxKey }, "STS");
};
...
```

Any help would be most welcome,

Thanks,

Greg.

Comment: What language is this? This looks like a programming issue -- belonging on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Shell javascript run by mongo shell. Is there a way to move it to stackoverflow?

Comment: I'm no Javascript language guru, but maybe it should be `db.tags().remove` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Misplaced " - took me a while to see it!

```
db.tags.remove({ _id: { ns: "mydb.mycoll", "min": { **"day:"** MinKey }}, tag: "LTS" });
db.tags.remove({ _id: { ns: "mydb.mycoll", "max": { **"day:"** MaxKey }}, tag: "STS" });
```

Change it to `"day" :`